# Azure How to Enable Soft Delete on a Managed Disk?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have a managed disk NOT a storage account. And I would like to protect it from accidental deletion.

Is there an equivalent to soft delete for a managed disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Is there an equivalent to soft delete for a managed disk?
```

No, at present there is no option of soft delete for a Managed Disk in Azure.

Currently we have soft delete option for storage account and

Also [Soft delete for virtual machines in Azure Backup](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/soft-delete-virtual-machine-backup/).